# Call JavaScript for custom added class for Wordpress WPBakery Visual Composer Post Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I added a class (format-date) to a custom field in Post Grid but I can't seem to apply any JS to it.

```
<div class="vc_gitem-post-meta-field-_EventStartDate format-date vc_gitem-align-left"> 2015-10-08 07:30:00</div>
```

Simple jQuery test:

```
$('.format-date').addClass('test')
```

Code is in the footer and I've tried `$(window).load(function() $(document).ready(function()`. No JS errors in Fire Bug.

I suspect it's due to the loading animation applied to the posts. How can I call my JS after this has loaded?

Answer (score 7):

This worked:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: The issue was Visual Composer loads Post Grid via ajax. Using $(document).ajaxStop(function() { allows me to call any JS after all of their ajax calls.